# Is it possible to afford the Bucking Bronco vigor at the fair?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Early in the game, before things really start to go downhill, there's a fair and a vending machine that sells the Bucking Bronco vigor.

There are ways to get some cash before this point, and I believe you can backtrack for some limited time afterwards to this location, but I can't seem to get together enough cash to afford this Vigor.

Is there any way to buy it at this stage?  Or am I limited to waiting and finding it later?

Comment: Preordering got you the Industrial Revolution pack which includes $500 silver eagles. I don`t know if you get access to it right away though.

Comment: yeah the $500 can you only get later on in a bar that you need to go trugh. You get all items from codes in this room. Example the gear and weapon from the puzzle and the gear from the Premium Edition ;)

Comment: you get it pretty early no reason to buy it in my opinion.

Comment: @Paralytic, the early going is *rough* in 1999 Mode.  If I could have had Bronco and a half dozen charges before I got my shield for instance, I could have saved a few reloads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't buy it in the fair, it's just there to tease you(and to give you a vendor to "hack" with Possession).

Even if you collect all of the money you find scattered around Columbia and win both the first and the second prize at the shooting games at the fair, you'll end up with about 150 $, less than half of the price of the Bucking Bronco vigor.

Also, if you think about it from a gameplay point, getting it this early would trivialize the first part of the game. Take the first Fireman you meet, for example: it's supposed to be the first "miniboss", but using Bucking Bronco on him would render him completely harmless.

UPDATE: according to [this article](http://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/Easter_Eggs_and_Secrets) the vigor vendor you find at the fair is the remnant of the E3 demo. At the time the Salt system wasn't implemented yet, and the vigor bottles had "charges"

Answer (score 0):

Once I got my possession, I retraced steps all the way back to the beginning as far as I could go with the vigor to see what I can do. The possession can only be used on the vendor to receive some money and by the time I am supposed to use the vigor on the ticket vendor I ended up with 182 coins, still not nearly enough. It's not possible to get the Bucking Bronco vigor.

Answer (score 0):

At the very start when you find possesion, use it on a vending machine, refill your salts and repeat. This couldn't unlock the bucking bronco for me, but with a few hours of grinding, I bought the possesion for less upgrade. Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you have to wait until later. I think it is there just as a tease.
I could be wrong though.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. You have to use money hacks. Use something decent like cheat engine.

Comment: Do you have any proof that it is possible through these means? That would make for an interesting additional answer if you discussed how to do it and what the effects were.

Comment: @twobugs PROOF. It works, And its powered by salts