# Where can I find the Possession For Less upgrade?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

While playing Bioshock Infinite, I came across a Vigor vending machine with the 2nd possession upgrade in it (lowers cost of using possession).  I didn't have enough money, so I simply passed it by assuming I'd see it again.

I've gone a long way (and now have enough money) and none of the subsequent vigor vendors have that specific upgrade.  Did I miss it and will never be able to have it now?  I read somewhere that the upgrades in the vending machines "stack" and once seen, they'll be available in later ones and that seems true for all of the rest, just not the one I want.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Edit: This is for the XBox 360 version in case this is a bug.

Comment: I seem to have encountered the same issue on PC. After I saw the upgrade once and didn't have enough cash to buy it, I never saw it again.

Comment: @Tacroy and HenryAdamsJr: Where did you see the first "Possession For Less" upgrade? I would like to get it at an early part of the game in my next playthrough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered this same problem on PC. Later on in the game, after the encounter with the Siren, I found Possession For Less again. Perhaps the first chance at purchase for this upgrade is meant as incentive/reward for those who grinded mobs or scavenged thoroughly for Silver Eagles.

Comment: 360 version here, and I can verify it does come back in the same spot as on PC.

Comment: @aviangentile and Yawus: Where did you see the first "Possession For Less" upgrade? I would like to get it at an early part of the game in my next playthrough.

Comment: `"after the encounter with the Siren"`...

Comment: @Yawus Are you addressing [this comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113268/where-can-i-find-the-possession-for-less-upgrade#comment152153_113286) as a reply to me? If yes, please @ tag my username next time, so I would be notified. I'm talking about the *first* time you saw the "Possession For Less" upgrade, not the second time in the later part of the game.

Comment: @galacticninja If I'm not mistaken, it comes in the first Vigor upgrade machine you come across.

Comment: @aviangentile I believe the first Vigor upgrade machine (Veni Vidi Vigor) is at the Welcome Center (the fair), which [only offers Bucking Bronco](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/112210/4797) and the next is at Raffle Square, which [only offers 'Possession Aid'](http://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/Possession_Aid). I've checked all Vigor upgrade machines up to [Monument Tower](http://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/Monument_Tower), but am still to come across Possession for Less.

Comment: I eventually found it in Fink's Factory.  Either it just wasn't showing up in machines after the Hall of Heroes, or it was a bug that was fixed before I got to the factory.

Answer (score 3):

You first find it at [Hall of Heroes Gift Shop](http://www.ign.com/wikis/bioshock-infinite/Hall_of_Heroes_Gift_Shop).  It'll cost you $1653. The item will appear in vending machines later on in the game.

[image]